# Macro Advice - Pasting Rows into a new worksheet, if certain cells read "NO"

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I would like some advice using VBA and Macros.

I would a way to link worksheets (*worksheets 1 to 6*) with a master sheet (*worksheet 7*).

If the row contains **"NO"** in column `I` (throughout *worksheets 1 to 6*), can the code copy and paste that row into *worksheet 7*?

Then if the row (in *worksheets 1 to 6*) was changed to **"YES"**  will another code be able to delete that row from *worksheet 7*?

For some context, *worksheets 1 to 6* are a list of jobs and the **'YES'** & **'NO'** are if the client has paid. If **'NO'** they are added to the debtors list on *worksheet 7*. If **'YES'** they need to be removed from the list of debtors.

Comment: please note that this isn't a free code writing service. Please post what you've already tried and ask specific questions, but not ask for entire solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you:

```
Public Sub debtors()
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim wksdest As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wksdest = wkb.Sheets("Sheet7")
    wksdest.Rows.Clear 'Clear the contents of Sheet7
    destRow = 1 'First row on Sheet7
    For i = 1 To 6 'Loop through Sheets 1 to 6
        newIndex = Right(Str(i), 1)
        thisSheet = "Sheet" + newIndex
        Set wks = wkb.Sheets(thisSheet)
        wks.Activate
        'Selects column I
        Columns("I:I").Select
        'Find a coincidence with the string "NO"
        Set cell = Selection.Find(What:="NO", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        'If there is a coincidence (is Not Nothing)
        If Not cell Is Nothing Then
            firstRow = cell.Row
            newRow = cell.Row
            'Copy the row and paste on Sheet7
            wks.Rows(newRow).Copy
            wksdest.Rows(destRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            destRow = destRow + 1
            foundValue = True
            'Find next coincidences in the same sheet
            While foundValue
                Set cell = Selection.FindNext(cell)
                If Not cell Is Nothing Then
                    newRow = cell.Row
                    If newRow <> firstRow Then
                        wks.Rows(newRow).Copy
                        wksdest.Rows(destRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        destRow = destRow + 1
                    Else
                        foundValue = False
                    End If
                Else
                    foundValue = False
                End If
            Wend
        End If
    Next i
    wksdest.Activate
End Sub
```

Open VBA/Macros with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, under *ThisWorkbook* insert a new module and paste the code on the right side.

Execute it clicking the green triangle.

I put comments on the code to let you understand how it works.

You can run it also step by step by clicking on the first line and then go through each step pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>.